# How to create uniform circular motion using quaternion in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

trying to rotate object both in sinusoidal and circular form along 3 axis

```
using UnityEngine;

public class time_behaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

float time;
public float rate;
public float x_axis_amplitude;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    time =Time.time;
    float x_rotation = x_axis_amplitude*Mathf.Asin(Mathf.Pow(Mathf.Sin(time*rate),2))*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    float y_rotation = 2*(Mathf.Acos(Mathf.Cos(time*rate))*Mathf.Rad2Deg);
    transform.localRotation =  Quaternion.Euler(x_rotation,y_rotation,0);
      
    
    Debug.Log(transform.rotation.eulerAngles);
}
}
```

here is the code
as you can see i am trying to revolve object in sin form along x axis and circularly along y axis
i got desired outcome for x axis but for y axis the rotation keep flipping after 360 degree ,
Is there anyway that after 360 degree it dont flip its motion and rotate forever

I have tried doing transform.Rotate() but it dont rotate uniformly,it just keeps object stationary at that angle

Comment: what would be a circular angle for you? You want to just increase the angle linear -> rotates around itself .... a circle to mean would mean it goes backwards on the axis whih doesn't seem to be what you want ? so basically just `float y_rotation = time * rate * 360;` or something like that

Comment: "trying to rotate object both in sinusoidal and circular form along 3 axis" do you mean to orbit around a center and waving up and down on that orbit? The formulas in Update() seem to do completely different motions.

Comment: @taiyo no I don't want a orbital path or orbit around anything i want to rotate at that point, yeah i realised calling it circular was misleading sorry for that